# IE 9 change url javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer, url

I want to change url on button click, what I do now:

```
$scope.onClick = function(url) {
    document.location=url;
    $scope.isPopOverOpen = false;
}
```

when `url=workspace/#/`the page URL becomes: `localhost:8080/workspace/#/dashboard`.

problem is that in IE 9 the page url becomes: `localhost:8080/workspace/workspace/#/dashboard` so I get page not found error.

Maybe someone knows why and solution for this?

I use angular, so maybe it can give right functionality.

Comment: which router are you using?

Comment: standard angular provided

Answer (score 0):

use [$location.path("/folder/" + url);](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location) just include the service

```
angular.module('app')
    .controller('myApp',[$location, function(...
```